# Frequently used functions, performance improvements using static variables?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, assembly, compiler, pic-ccs

Does defining variables (large arrays) as static inside a function have any performance improvements if the function is to be called repeatedly say in the order of seconds?

Comment: You've tagged this "assembly" but talk about "static". Did you mean in C instead?

Comment: This might depend on the addressing modes of the processor.  It's possible something that can do stack pointer relative addressing in hardware will be faster with automatic variables.  Something that can't or with good absolute addressing support may do better with static.  The fact that you are using an array further complicates things, as you need to find the base address and then access an offset from that.  But keep in mind that static variables claim space all the time, not just when being used.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - it's really both.  The conceptual term which frames the question comes from C, but the implementation detail on which it entirely depends is machine language, *usually* expressed in assembly mnemonics (rather than numeric opcodes) for human convenience.

Comment: One of the most useful things you could do would be to compile both options, then disassemble the result to examine.

Comment: Am I being a bit overly zealous, or should this question be moved to programmers.stackexchange, or a stackoverflow? It is an interesting question, just not for this ee.se. Also, there is too little information, I think we need to know what the context is (e.g. amd64 server vs 8bit embedded), or the CPU (amd64, Pic16, ...). IMHO, without knowing the CPU or context, the question is too vague to be answered with much more than conjecture.

Comment: It'd probably be best to get the tech sheets for your particular CPU; they generally tell you how many clock cycles each instruction takes in each available addressing mode.

Answer (score 2):

In short: it depends. On more things that you want to know.

Some architectures have instructions and/or addressing modes that access stack-relative data. Nearly all architectures have instructions and/or addressing modes that access data at an absolute address. Which is faster depends on the particular architecture.

Note that some architectures allow only a very small offset or (zero-page) address in an instruction, so on such an architecture a lot depends on whether the offset fits. When you have a lot of static (= global lifetime) variables, you are more likely to exceed a small zero-page address (because they share the same absolute address space) than with a lot of automatic (local lifetime, stack-offset addressed) variables (which each have their own small SP offset).

But on modern PC-class architectures the memory access (including cache issues) are often much more important that instruction execution, especially when the code is a tight loop and the data is all over the place. In such a case execution speed might vary by 10's of % depending on exactly how data is aligned with respect to various cache issues (lines, pages, buffers, etc.), which is affected by almost everything but the phase of the moon, including other applications that are or even have been loaded. This makes benchmarking in such a situation very dubious.

Answer (score 0):

Improvements compared to what?
I'm guessing you have a C program (or you are using C terminology to describe your program), and you want to compare

- (a) large array declared "const" in any scope
- (b) large array declared as static inside a function (function scope)
- (c) large array declared as static outside a function ("file" scope)
- (d) large array declared outside a function (global scope)
- (e) large array inside a function ("automatic", function scope) without an initializer
- (f) large array inside a function ("automatic", function scope) with an initializer

(Or is there something else you want to compare against?)

### automatic with initializer vs others

The biggest performance difference is between (f) and the others -- (f) copies the initializer to the array -- and zeroes out any remaining items -- every time you call the function.
The other use whatever happens to be in RAM at the time.

If the function usually uses only a few items of the array, but you need a very large array to handle corner cases, then (f) is going to waste a lot of time writing to every byte of the array every time you call it, compared to the other approaches that skip that initialization.

On the other hand, sometimes a function needs to have a modifiable array re-set a certain way every time you call it. When you choose (f), your compiler probably uses the most efficient way to do that -- it is unlikely that any of the other methods (followed by "manually" re-setting the array) will be faster.

### automatic vs others (stack-relative vs absolute)

Some compilers for some processors use exactly the same generic array access instruction for every type of array (a) through (f).
For those compilers, the particular type of array you choose has no effect on the runtime.

Often processors force a compiler to use different instructions to access different types of arrays.

In processors with cache, the differences between these instructions is generally insignificant.

However, most processors do not have cache, such as the 8-bit processors that outsell all 64-bit processors combined.
In those processors, the differences in the instructions picked by the compiler may lead to a noticeable difference in the runtime in a tight inner loop that accesses items in the array without a lot of other computation.

(My impression is that "automatic" stack-relative instructions are the fastest on ARM microcontrollers, while "absolute" instructions for global and "file static" and "function static" are the fastest on PIC16 microcontrollers).

Answer (score 0):

Generally it will be faster to access variables that have known addresses at build time.  However, the exact benefit, if any, depends on many other factors.  For example, which PIC?  Static as apposed to what type of dynamic allocation?  How large is the array?  If you are using a compiler, than this can depend on strategies picked by the compiler designer.

If you are comparing static (address known at build time) variables with dynamically allocating variables on the data stack, then static will be a win on a basic PIC 16 since those have no inherent stack functions.

On a PIC 18, there are some limited relative addressing capabilities off of FSRs, but these will still generally take more cycles than if a fixed address is known.  The offset from a pointer register is only 8 bits, so the reach is also limited.  Beyond that you have to do your own math to compute the address and load it into one of the FSRs.

On a 16 bit PIC, there are more register-relative addressing modes, which allow more flexible access to items on the stack.  However, there are even more addressing modes available if you don't have to go thru a register to get the base address.  In a few limited cases it may actually be faster access a 16 bit variable on the stack since the address of the stack is already in W15 whereas the static address of a variable may need to be loaded into a register first.  The penalty for accessing dynamic memory will be less on a 16 bit PIC, but I think overall accessing static memory will be faster.  There is also a section of data memory, called "near", that allows for special instructions not available for accessing the rest of data memory.  In some cases if you could arrange for the stack to be in near memory, but that wouldn't be the general case.

However, all that was considering individual variables.  You are asking about a large array, which makes things different again.  Elements of a array are going to be accessed indirectly with the address computed at runtime anyway, so whether the start address of the array is a constant or something that has to be grabbed or computed makes less of a difference overall.  On a PIC 18, the biggest issue is probably contention for the limited number of FSRs (hardware pointer registers), since there are only 3 of them, and most likely at least 1 is already allocated as the data stack pointer.  (The C18 compiler is "less than brilliant" in how it uses the PIC 18 pointers, and actually commandeers 2 of the 3 SFRs for it's own use.)  On a 16 bit PIC, the runtime cycles will be even less different.

So basically, allocate things statically when you can.  About the only reason not to on PICs is if you need to conserve memory and you know that significant amounts of dynamically allocated memory will never be allocated simultaneously.  For example, if two subroutines each need to use a 2 kB array for temporary use only, but these subroutines are never called from each other, then dynamically allocating the arrays when needed saves 2 kB overall compared to static allocation.

Another reason, particularly on a PIC 16 and PIC 18, is to allow special fast-access memory locations to be used as scratch inside each routine.  For example, on many PIC 16 the last 16 bytes of each bank access the same 16 bytes globally.  These limited memory locations are therefore quite useful as quick temporary scratch because they can be accessed regardless of the bank setting.  My convention is to reserve most of these as if they were registers in other processor architectures.  My routines therefore generally save the ones they will trash on the data stack on entry, and restore them on exit.  The access bank on a PIC 18 works similarly, although it is larger, so is easier to use for other things too.  This concept doesn't really apply to the 16 bit PICs because they have 16 real hardware registers built in.

So to recap, statically allocate all persistant state.  Then statically allocate the remaining state unless you need to reduce memory usage.